# TypeScript module types for UMD globals?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, umd

My TypeScript project is compiled for the browser with **AMD** modules. I include `lodash.min.js` myself, along with a bunch of other **UMD** libraries that all declare global variables, like `moment` and `_`. I need to tell my TypeScript about the global `_` variable for Lodash. How can I do this with imports? If I install `@types/lodash` and use `import * as _ from "lodash";`, it tries to dynamically fetch an AMD Lodash module at runtime, which breaks everything.

If I have one file where I declare the `_` global, i.e. `export declare const _: LodashStatic;`, I cannot even import my declaration in another file, or it tries to load stuff at runtime. What is even the point of the `declare` keyword if TypeScript treats it like a functioning import. I thought declarations just tell the compiler to shut up and that there will be separately loaded stuff at runtime. Lucky for me, I can use `declare const _: LodashStatic;` in every single one of my hundreds of files and everything works, but it would be nice if I could just declare it once and then import in other files...

Answer (score -1):

The usual way to tell Typescript about the existence of global types is through the `types` array in your `tsconfig.json`. If you have `@types/lodash` installed, then having the following in your `tsconfig.json` should allow you to reference `_` anywhere:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": ["lodash"]
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. It gives me messages telling me not to use UMD globals within modules.